# How to Modify selected option text & Restore Back text after next option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Modify text contents of dynamically generated drop down list using jQuery. Here is my example:

Drop Down Text look like below:

```
<select id="s1">
  <option data-name="volvo" value="1">1:Volvo</option>
  <option data-name="saab" value="2">2:Saab</option>
  <option data-name="mercedes"  value="3">3:Mercedes</option>
  <option data-name="audi"  value="4">4:Audi</option>
  <option data-name="BMW" value="11">11:BMW</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
var previous;
$('#s1').focus(function () {
  // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
  previous = this.value;        
}).change(function() {    
  //Modify the SelectedOption Display only Number Value 
  $('#s1').find(':selected').text($('#s1').find(':selected').val());
  //Restore the Previous Option : Format 'Number Value : data-name'
  alert($("#s1 option[value='"+previous+"']").val());
  alert($("#s1 option[value='"+previous+"']").attr('data-name'));
  $("#s1 option[value='"+previous+"']").text($("#s1 option[value='"+previous+"']").val() +' '+ $("#s1 option[value='"+previous+"']").attr('data-name'));        
});
```

I also used following attributes :

- `value`: stores number value of that car
- `data-name`: stores the Name of that Car

This is what I want:
Whenever any user select any option, then the selected option text will be modified and removes that Name part: For example: selecting 1:Volvo become  1 only.However if user select another option then the previous option text will be restore back to previous format e.g: 1 becomes 1:Volvo again. That is why i used given attributes to restore format.
I have written a code that works fine if i used `alert` .But i want to do it without using `alert` and then it does not work.

Here is my code:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w65w8hd5/10/)
please help.

Comment: focus and change events are likely interfering here, resp. are happening in different order than you expect. ("Holding" executing via UI blocking alerts can easily disguise that fact.) I would use only change (and click, if activating the option visible by default is supposed to achieve the same thing) events here, and do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/w65w8hd5/13/ (If you want to restore the original option texts, you'll need to either store capitalized names into data-name to begin with, or capitalize via script - not that easy, if stuff like BMW is involved.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `data-name` and `value` attributes, so you can easily loop over the `option`s and use those attributes to update the text:

```
$('#s1').change(function() {    
  $(this).find('option').each(function(){
    $(this).text(
      $(this).attr('value')+( $(this).is(':selected') ? '' : ':'+$(this).attr('data-name'))
    );
  });
});
```

```js
$('#s1').change(function() {    
  $(this).find('option').each(function(){
    $(this).text(
      $(this).attr('value')+( $(this).is(':selected') ? '' : ':'+$(this).attr('data-name'))
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option data-name="volvo" value="1">1:Volvo</option>
  <option data-name="saab" value="2">2:Saab</option>
  <option data-name="mercedes"  value="3">3:Mercedes</option>
  <option data-name="audi"  value="4">4:Audi</option>
  <option data-name="BMW" value="11">11:BMW</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT** (comment)
I'd say that with a *normal* usage, the code above will have no impact on user experience. It will be slower in a *mathematics(?)* meaning - negligible differences in execution time, as DOM is modified (each `<option>` is updated) inside `$.each()` loop, which isn't the best idea. But nothing that usar can notice.

For the OP example, where only 5 options are involved, it's arguable that updating all of them VS updating only 2, won't make any difference in *speed*. If there would be hundrets of options, then (speaking about user experience) I, as a user, wouldn't be so glad having so many options to pass through, searching the one I need. So the main issue would be there.

But, if there are any concerns about the above script speed, there's another (a better?) way, without using global flags and loops.
It creates a temporary `data-last` attribute for identifying previously selected `<option>` and only two options are modified at a time :

```
$('#s1').change(function() {    
  $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-last','Yes').text(this.value)
  .siblings('[data-last]').removeAttr('data-last').text(function(){
    return this.value+':'+$(this).attr('data-name');
  });
});
```

```js
$('#s1').change(function() {    
  $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-last','Yes').text(this.value)
    .siblings('[data-last]').removeAttr('data-last').text(function(){
    return this.value+':'+$(this).attr('data-name');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option data-name="volvo" value="1">1:Volvo</option>
  <option data-name="saab" value="2">2:Saab</option>
  <option data-name="mercedes"  value="3">3:Mercedes</option>
  <option data-name="audi"  value="4">4:Audi</option>
  <option data-name="BMW" value="11">11:BMW</option>
</select>
```

---

And there's a speed comparison between these two methods (200 options) :

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L1wrm8h6/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Artur Filipiak. It worked.I also want to know that are these code building the each of the option every time user select an option? will it make the drop down list slower for more options? Thanks

Comment: arround 200 option.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited wrong fiddle in prev comment :-) https://jsfiddle.net/w65w8hd5/19/